# Closed Form and Pullback compatibility

Tags: differential-forms

given:

$U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^N, f\in C^1(V,U)$ a diffeomorphism

Let $\omega$ be a k-Form on U and $f^*\omega$ a closed Form.

Then with $ 0 = df^*(\omega)  = d \omega(df)$ we have ,that $\omega$ is a closed Form. Is this correct?

Comment: What does $d\omega(df)$ mean?

Comment: that is the definition of the pullback right? $f^*(\omega) = \omega(df)$ where $df$ is the total differential of f

Comment: Not quite. $(f^*\omega)_p(X_1, \dots, X_k) = \omega_{f(p)}(df(X_1), \dots, df(X_k))$.

Comment: ok. But that would be the same in terms of showing that $\omega$ is a  closed Form. Because $0=d(f^*\omega)_p(X_1, \dots, X_k) = d\omega_{f(p)}(df(X_1), \dots, df(X_k))$

Comment: Not quite. It could be that $d\omega_{f(p)}(Y_1, \dots, Y_k) \neq 0$, but there is no $X_1, \dots, X_k$ such that $df(X_i) = Y_i$. You need to use the additional information about $f$.

Comment: @Michael Albanese: $f$ was supposed to be a diffeomorphism, hence $df$ is an isomorphism of tangent spaces at echt point. Hence those $X_i$ exist for sure. But actually the proof should be purely formal, as you see in my answer.

Comment: I am well aware of that @Moos, I was trying to help the OP reach that conclusion. Also, the proof is purely formal once certain things have been proved. It is not clear to me the OP has proved these things yet.

Comment: I don't get it. Why does $df$ beeing an isomorphism help me in this case?

Comment: just to assure that i got it right. $df$ is bijective because $f$ is bijective and $df$ is also linear so $df$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: $df : T_pU \to T_{f(p)}V$ is an isomorphism because $f$ is a diffeomorphism. Therefore, for any $Y_1, \dots, Y_k \in T_{f(p)}V$, there are $X_1, \dots, X_k$ such that $df(X_i) = Y_i$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f^*$ is an isomorphism of vector-spaces of $(k+1)$-forms, hence $0=df^*\omega = f^*d\omega$ implies $d\omega=0$.